# Do enzymatic pet urine cleaners also clean human urine?

Tags: flooring, cleaning, smell, carpet

Do enzymatic pet urine cleaners also clean human urine that is present in carpeting and carpet padding?

Specifically, human urine that has been present in carpeting and carpet padding for years.

Answer (score 3):

When my son was little, we had a few accidents that we didn't find out until it had set. Carpet cleaners used to clean up animal urine worked great to neutralize it. I don't know about actually being "clean"; it never made sense to me that you wouldn't want to carpet clean it after neutralizing it. Personally, I've had best success with Folex Instant Carpet Spot Remover. It's not expensive and pretty safe.

HOWEVER, extended saturation of urine seems to melt carpet padding over time from what I've seen. My recommendation is spray an area heavily and carpet clean it the day after. If there is improvement, but not enough, try it again. If this does not greatly reduce the smell, you may need to replace the carpet.