# Do enzymatic urine cleaners work on old urine in carpeting and carpet padding?

Tags: cleaning, smell, carpet

Related to my [previous question regarding urine in carpeting and carpet padding](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/239303/do-enzymatic-pet-urine-cleaners-also-clean-human-urine), I would like to learn if enzymatic cleaners work for urine that has been present in carpeting or carpet padding for 10 years.

Since the enzymes are designed to eat the urine, I'm wondering if urine that has been present in the carpeting for so long would still be edible by the enzymes after such a long time.

There is no visible stain, only the smell (odor) of urine.

(Sorry for the 2 related questions, but people prefer each post be limited to one specific question.)

Comment: They might, but think they do better on recent stains/smells.  Imagine after that time the smell has gone into the floor below the carpet.  Might need to remove carpet and work directly on the floor.  Liquid tends to spread out a lot.

Comment: @crip659 Thanks. In this case, I'm 98% sure the floor under the carpeting is concrete.  Now whether or not that concrete would be sealed, I have no idea.

Comment: It might, but you risk the enzymes getting sick and dying from eating rotten food! :) On a more serious note, the best way to find out is to give it a try. Also, don't apologize for following the rules and posting multiple questions! That is _exactly_ the way it should be done and is a good example for others to follow.

Comment: In my experience, no.